# Is there any upper limit on publishing Android app bundle on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

Our .aab file size has exceeded 150 MB. I want to know whether we can publish the .aab file of more than 150 MB file on the Play Store.

As per the developer docs:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

> Publishing with Android App Bundles also increases the app size limit to 150MB without having to use APK expansion files. Keep in mind, this limit applies only to the actual download size, not the publishing size. So, users can download apps as large as 150MB

According to the documentation, I understood that we can publish the .aab more than 150 MB, but when the user downloads the APK from Play Store, the APK size should be within the 150 MB limit.

Is my understanding correct here?

Answer (score 4):

Read this part of docs
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#size_restrictions

As it is stated that

Compressed download size restriction

While publishing with Android App Bundles helps your users install your app with the smallest download possible, compressed downloads are limited to 150 MB. That is, when a user downloads your app, the total size of the compressed APKs required to install your app (for example, the base APK + configuration APK(s)) must be no more than 150 MB. Any subsequent downloads, such as downloading a dynamic feature (and its configuration APK(s)) on demand, must also meet this compressed download size restriction.

When you upload your app bundle, if the Play Console finds any of the possible downloads of your app or its on demand features to be more than 150 MB, you get an error

Answer (score 4):

This week, my Android App Bundle's size reached 161MB after introducing several new features. I was frightened that my aab's size  exceeds the size limitation of Android App Bundles. But I tried to upload the oversize aab to the Google Play and it worked. I was confused and did many research to figure it out, here's  what I got.

**Can my Android App Bundle's size be over 150MB?**

Yes, Android App Bundles's size can be over 150MB. As the official Android Developer Document [Android App Bundles-Compressed download size restriction](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#size_restrictions) said, the total size of the compressed APKs required to install our app (for example, the base APK + configuration APKs) must be no more than 150 MB, rather than the Android App Bundles's size.

**How to measure the size range of compressed APKs from my app bundle?**

Although Android App Bundles's size can be over 150MB, we must be curious about the real size range of compressed APKs, as we wanna know the left available size for our app to use.

Fortunately, Google shared methods to [estimate our app’s download size](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#measure_size) for a given device configuration. This is helpful to better understand the user experience of downloading our app and checking whether our app meets the [compressed download size restriction](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#size_restrictions) for app bundles or [enabling instant experiences](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/overview#reduce-size).

After you build your Android App Bundle, you should test how Google Play uses it to generate APKs and how those APKs behave when deployed to a device. There are two ways you should consider testing your app bundle: locally using the `bundletool` command line tool and through Google Play by [uploading your bundle to the Play Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle) and using a test track.

When `bundletool` generates APKs from your app bundle, it includes them in a container called an *APK set archive*, which uses the `.apks` file extension. To generate an APK set for all device configurations your app supports from your app bundle, use the `bundletool build-apks` command, as shown below.

```bash
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

To measure the estimated download sizes of APKs in an APK set as they would be served compressed over-the-wire, use the `get-size total` command:

```bash
bundletool get-size total --apks=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

My Android App Bundle `/MyApp/my_app.aab`'s size is 161MB. Here's the result I got from `bundletool get-size total` command, which means the size range of compressed APKs from my app bundle is between 105632514 Bytes to 111835648 Bytes. `111835648 Bytes` is equal to `106.65MB`, which  is less than `150MB`. Therefore, we figure out that my Android App Bundle have 43.35MB left available size to use.

```bash
bogon:bundletool happylee$ bundletool get-size total --apks=/MyApp/my_app.apks
MIN,MAX
105632514,111835648
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems google finally increased the allowed app size to 200mb.

> Publishing with Android App Bundles helps your users to install your app with the smallest downloads possible and increases the compressed download size limit to 200 MB. That is, when a user downloads your app, the total size of the compressed APKs required to install your app (for example, the base APK + configuration APKs) must be no more than 200 MB.

Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle